# Example from Microsoft F# documentation doesn't compile

Tags: f#

MS documentation: [Use interfaces to group related operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#use-interfaces-to-group-related-operations)

```ml
type Serializer =
    abstract Serialize<'T>: preserveRefEq: bool -> value: 'T -> string
    abstract Deserialize<'T>: preserveRefEq: bool -> pickle: string -> 'T
```

If I copy and paste that into an `fsx` script or a `dotnet-interactive` notebook, I'll get a compiler error that says:

```
This construct is deprecated: ':' is not permitted as a character in operator names and is reserved for future useF# Compiler(35)
```

What changes would I need to make in order to fix this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just adding a space before the colon fixes it:

```
type Serializer =
    abstract Serialize<'T> : preserveRefEq: bool -> value: 'T -> string
    abstract Deserialize<'T> : preserveRefEq: bool -> pickle: string -> 'T
```

This might be a compiler bug.

Comment: There is an open issue to fix the compiler: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/4607. For now, I will just fix the example code to make it compile.